# Why is Swing supported in newer JavaSE versions, but not JavaFX?

Tags: java, oracle, swing, javafx

I find JavaFX from my perspective more modern and better to use than Swing.

I read a document about the [future of JavaFX](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/java-client-roadmap-updates) written by an [Oracle employee](https://blogs.oracle.com/author/donald-smith) and came across a sentence:

> Oracle is reaffirming that Swing and AWT remain core Java SE
> technologies to Oracle across all Java SE releases and support
> timelines.

**Why is Swing supported in newer JavaSE versions, but not JavaFX?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a business question.

One answer is that they wanted to be able to separate the JavaFX release cycle from the main Java SE release cycle.  Though as it turns out JavaFX is following the new Java SE release cadence.

A second answer is that separating them possibly makes project governance simpler.

> But why JavaFX and not Swing?

Again, business reasons:

- JavaFX is perceived as more "niche" than Swing is.  So splitting it out is perceived as more acceptable.
- Swing (and AWT) are widely used technologies in old projects.  And by old, I mean "mature" / "legacy" projects that have been around for over 20 years.  Separating Swing is more likely to break more old projects.

  Major changes that "break" old customer code or practices are bad for Oracle's business model.  They annoy corporate customers who pay substantial Java license fees, who might be considering a "strategic" switch to some other language.
- Swing (and AWT) are not under active development, and hence they won't normally present such a drag on the main Java SE schedule as JavaFX may do.

---

Anyway, this is all moot.  The decision to split out JavaFX and not Swing was made years ago.  It happened.  Live with it.

Comment: If Swing (and AWT) are not in active development and JavaFX is separated from Java, how is it possible to develop future desktop applications, I mean, nobody would develop desktop applications with Swing and AWT because it is not being developed further. Is Oracle in the process of developing a new technology that will enable the development of desktop applications? The action Oracle has taken still annoys me very much.

Comment: Annoyed is a feeling.

Comment: How do you develop desktop applications with Java?

Comment: I don't develop desktop applications with Java.  But I don't see what the problem with using JavaFX is.  Just use it as if it was a 3rd-party library.  Or use jlink and / or jpackage to build executables, etetera.

Comment: @ayvygx If you use a build tool (i.e. Maven or Gradle) it's very simple to include JavaFX in your project; especially if you use the provided plugins. The only difficulty comes from deploying the application since JavaFX is platform-specific (though that doesn't matter as much when using `jlink` / `jpackage` since both create platform-specific, self-contained applications anyway).